# JavaScript - Spotify API, fetching playlist tracks

Tags: javascript, html, spotify, phonegap

I am using spotify api to search for the playlists and then display them in my mobile application. I am using Ajax to get the information from the api which works fine yet I can't seem to be able to populate the div with the results and make it possible for the application to play music snippets as it doesn't want to allow event listeners. You won't be able to see all the variables used but everything before this code works perfectly fine.

```
var audioObject = null;
//Spotify page
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#spotify', function(){
console.log("Spotify");
$('#search').on('click', function() {
    //e.preventDefault();
    searchstring = cweather;

    if (!searchstring){
        console.log('no input');
        return;
    }
    console.log(searchstring);
    searchPlaylist(searchstring);
});

});

var userId;

var searchPlaylist = function () {
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + spotifyAccessToken,
    },
    data: {
        q: searchstring,
        type: 'playlist',
        market: 'GB',
        offset: '0',
        limit: '5',
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);

        var items = response.playlists.items;
        var resultsintohtml = '';

        $.each(items, function(index) {
            var id = items[index].id;
            var name = items[index].name;
            //var image = items[index].image[1].url;
            userId = items[index].owner.id;
            console.log(id, name, userId);
            resultsintohtml += '<div style="backgroundColor="red"" data-album-id="' + id + '" class="cover"></div>';
        });

        console.log(resultsintohtml);
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = resultsintohtml;

        addclickevents();
    }
});
};

var fetchTracks = function (playlistsId, userId, callback) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + userId + '/playlists/' + playlistsId,
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + spotifyAccessToken,
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        callback(response);
    }
});
};

var addclickevents = function () {
$('.cover').click(function (e){
    console.log('get song');
    var target = $(this);

    if (target.hasClass('playing')) {
        audioObject.pause();
    } else {
        if (audioObject){
            audioObject.pause();
        }

        fetchTracks(target.data('playlist-id'), function (data) {
            audioObject = new
            Audio(data.tracks.items[0].preview_url);
            audioObject.play();
            target.addClass('playing');             
        });
        audioObject.addEventListener('pause', function(){
            target.removeClass('playing');
        });
    }
});
};
```

As this code is used I get following errors:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcQg0.png)
I have tried renaming the variables yet I get the very same error. I have double checked if there is any missing information from the spotify yet I am using all the available ID's already. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move the binding inside `fetchTracks()`, after assigning Audio to `audioObject` and you won't get the error (and `playing` class will be removed from element on pausing the track).

Comment: No quite sure which part of the code is the 'binding'. I am not very good with the terminology, apologies.

Comment: `addEventListener` is commonly called a binding. You bind some functionality on an event. That needs to happen after you have assigned a new Audio to your variable, which happens inside `fetchTracks`. That's when you want to bind. See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** looking closer to your code, I just noticed `fetchTracks` expects 3 parameters and you're passing only 2. The second parameter should be `userId` and the third should be the callback. I don't have a clue what your `userId` is, but, assuming it's `123` you should run the function like this:

```
...
fetchTracks(target.data('playlist-id'), "123", function (data) {
  audioObject = new Audio(data.tracks.items[0].preview_url);
  audioObject.play();
  target.addClass('playing');             
  audioObject.addEventListener('pause', function(){
    target.removeClass('playing');
  });
});
...
```

Considering, your code is, most likely, calling a broken URL from Spotify's point of view (which should show up as an error in your console - most likely, a `404` but possibly also `403` or `422`).

---

**Initial answer:**

Assuming the code above is what's generating the error, at line `87` (in the above snippet), you're trying to add an event listener on `audioObject`. According to the error, `audioObject` is not a DOM element, but `null`. So you might want to check if the element supports the method before applying it:

```
...
if (audioObject)
   audioObject.addEventListener('pause', function(){
     target.removeClass('playing');
   });
```

or...

```
if (audioObject instanceof Element)
   audioObject.addEventListener('pause', function(){
     target.removeClass('playing');
   });
```

**Note** (as future reference): whenever you decide to post images of code instead of the code itself on [SO], expect being down-voted.

Another **note**: the above does not fix the logic of your application, which is clearly broken (or at least not working as intended). It just avoids executing the code when it would generate an error.

---

You probably want add the event listener inside `fetchTracks()`:

```
...
fetchTracks(target.data('playlist-id'), function (data) {
  audioObject = new Audio(data.tracks.items[0].preview_url);
  audioObject.play();
  target.addClass('playing');             
  audioObject.addEventListener('pause', function(){
    target.removeClass('playing');
  });
});
...
```

..., but, without a minimal working example I can't be sure.

Comment: Close, but not quite the root cause.

Comment: @Sean: have i missed any `addEventListener`?

Comment: I have changed the code to the following to test it out and still get the same error.

Comment: If you moved the binding inside `fetchTracks` as shown in the last part of my answer and still get the same error, either you haven't cleared your cache or the error is caused by some other part of your application, which you haven't shown here.

Comment: You are right. My cache wasn't cleared. The error is gone but I still can't play the songs or pause them. The div's are filled with the 'playlists'.

Comment: I can't help you anymore by looking at dead code and chances are nobody else can. Your best bet is creating a [mcve].

Comment: @Kon, I figured it out: you're not passing the `userId` as the second param. See the update to my answer.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu `userId` gets called in the `var searchPlaylist` function as it stores the data about the user who has created the playlist. I have applied your code to mine yet unfortunately it still does not play any music.

Comment: As this has answered the initial question and fixed the missing parts of the code I will accept this answer as the right answer. Yet in case of future whoever looks back at this I recommend looking closer at the Spotify API call as it has been a big part which has been causing havoc in this code.

Comment: @Kon: according to their docs, the `userId` is an identifier string. Read [here](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/#spotify-uris-and-ids). You need to get that string from current user and pass it as `userId` to your `fetchTracks()` function, as second param, before the `callback`.

Answer (score 0):

If `audioObject` is only assigned a value in the callback of `fetchTracks`, it won't be defined when `audioObject.addEventListener` is called.

When you click on a `.cover`, the event listener is called.
If the cover does not have the "playing" class, then:

- the `audioObject` is still null
- `fetchTracks` will be called but the callback will not fire until the response is received
- `audioObject.addEventListener` will be called *but* the `audioObject` is `null`
- the response for `fetchTracks` come back, and in the callback you set audioObject to be an instance of Audio

Is there any reason why you chose to add the event listener outside of the callback?

Comment: The AudioObject is predefined before the start of the functions and its defined as AudioObject = null;
I have missed it by accident due to it being next to the access token which I did not want to share. See edit.

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain the execution order. The problem is the callback passed in to `fetchTracks` is run *after* you try and add the event listener to `null`.